# How to stop two nested divs with absolute positioning from overlapping each other?

Tags: css, responsive-design, tailwind-css, css-position, overlapping

I have a responsiveness issue with the project that I am currently developing

I have a sidebar with two nested divs (the sections that appear "separated" from each other - see preview below) with absolute positioning that are overlapping each other whenever the screen height is lower than the space required to fit all of the elements on screen.

[Overlapping Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n728l.gif)

I would like to know how to stop the bottom section from overlapping the top section and make the sidebar's content scrollable from that point (once the "SOUND DETECTION DETAILS" container begins to overlap the "STROBE DURATION" container).

Here's the relevant index.html body section code:

```
<body class="bg-black">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sidebar-container" class="py-1.5 bg-gray-300 w-400px h-full absolute z-1 overflow-x-hidden opacity-100">
            <div id="sidebar-logo" class="w-[300px] mx-auto">
                <img class="" src="assets\img\logo-V2\logo-horizontal-black.png">
            </div>

            <hr class="w-[375px] border border-solid border-zinc-700 mx-auto">

            <h3 class="text-center py-3 text-xl text-gray-600 font-semibold">STROBE SYNC MODE</h3>

            <div id="auto-manual-container" class="w-[330px] ml-35px flex justify-between">
                <button id="auto" class="w-[150px] h-10 mb-4 bg-white rounded font-bold text-xl text-themeOrange selected" onclick="autoMode()">AUTO</button>
                <button id="manual" class="w-[150px] h-10 mb-4 bg-white rounded font-bold text-xl text-gray-700" onclick="manualMode();">MANUAL</button>
            </div>

            <hr class="w-[375px] border border-solid border-zinc-700 mx-auto">

            <div id="auto-mode-container" class=""> <!-- "AM" stands for "Auto Mode" -->
                <div id="input-device-container" class="w-[330px] ml-35px">
                    <h5 class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500">INPUT DEVICE</h5>

                    <select id="select-input-device" class="w-full h-10 mb-5 flex mx-auto bg-white rounded outline-none font-semibold text-center text-gray-700" required>
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>SELECT DEVICE</option>
                        <option value="" class="device text-left">&nbsp;Integrated Player</option>
                        <option value="" class="device text-left">&nbsp;Example Device</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div id="frequency-range-focus-container" class="w-[330px] ml-35px">
                    <h5 class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500">FREQUENCY RANGE FOCUS</h5>

                    <div id="low-mid-high-container" class="w-full flex justify-between">
                        <button id="low" class="w-[100px] h-6 mb-4 pt-[2px] bg-white rounded font-bold text-base text-themeOrange selected" onclick="low_Btn()">LOW</button>
                        <button id="mid" class="w-[100px] h-6 mb-4 pt-[2px] bg-white rounded font-bold text-base text-gray-700" onclick="mid_Btn()">MID</button>
                        <button id="high" class="w-[100px] h-6 mb-4 pt-[2px] bg-white rounded font-bold text-base text-gray-700" onclick="high_Btn()">HIGH</button>
                    </div>
                    <button id="master" class="w-full h-12 mb-3 pt-[2px] bg-white rounded font-bold text-base text-gray-700" onclick="master_Btn()">MASTER</button>
                </div>

                <div id="detection-sensitivity-container" class="w-[330px] ml-35px">
                    <h5 id="sens-label" class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500"></h5>

                    <div id="sens-slider-container" class="w-full">
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="sens-slider w-full" id="sens-slider">
                        <p class="float-left font-regular text-sm text-gray-600">0</p>
                        <p class="float-right font-regular text-sm text-gray-600">100</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div id="strobe-duration-container" class="w-[330px] ml-35px">
                    <h5 id="AM-duration-label" class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500"></h5>

                    <div id="duration-slider-container" class="duration-slider-container">
                        <input type="range" min="10" max="1000" value="200" class="duration-slider w-full" id="AM-duration-slider">
                        <p class="float-left font-regular text-sm text-gray-600">10</p>
                        <p class="float-right font-regular text-sm text-gray-600">1000</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div id="sound-detection-details-container" class="w-[330px] ml-35px absolute bottom-[75px]">
                    <h5 class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500">SOUND DETECTION DETAILS</h5>

                    <div id="SDD-container" class="w-full h-40 px-4 bg-white rounded flex flex-col justify-evenly">
                        <div id="SCT-container" class="w-full">
                            <h4 class="float-left font-semibold text-base text-gray-600">SOUND COME THROUGH</h4>
                            <label id="SCT-check-container" class="float-right">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked disabled> <!-- only check when audio coming trough, change with javascript -->
                                <span class="SCT-checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <hr>
                        
                        <div id="tempo-container" class="w-full">
                            <h4 class="float-left font-semibold text-base text-gray-600">TEMPO:</h4>
                            <h4 id="bpm" class="float-right font-semibold text-base text-gray-600">150BPM</h4> <!-- change with javascript -->
                        </div>

                        <hr>
                        
                        <div id="audio-meter-container" class="w-full">
                            <h4 class="float-left font-semibold text-base text-gray-600">AUDIO METER</h4>
                            <label id="AM-check-container" class="float-right"><!-- in this context "AM" stands for "Audio Meter" -->
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="AM-checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div id="AM-on-off-container" class="w-[330px] ml-35px flex justify-between absolute bottom-0">
                    <button id="AM-off" class="w-[150px] h-10 mb-4 bg-white rounded font-bold text-xl text-themeOrange selected" onclick="AM_turnOff()">OFF</button>
                    <button id="AM-on" class="w-[150px] h-10 mb-4 bg-white rounded font-bold text-xl text-gray-700" onclick="AM_turnOn();">ON</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am using Tailwind CSS, however, I do understand pure CSS answers as i am able to convert them to Tailwinds fromatting. Thanks!

I have searched for hours trying to find a solution for a problem similar to mine, but with no avail. I have found tutorials with a context similar to mine but the elements' positioning were not of the same type.

Comment: Do they have to be absolutely positioned? This could be done with flexbox or grid.

Comment: I have tried using flexbox to solve this, however, when positioning the bottom elements to flex-end, for some reason a lot of extra empty space is added between the containers that are supposed to be separated, pushing the elements outside of the page's view range (without having to scroll down). Plus, it makes the sidebar scrollable, which I don´t want to happen unless the screen height isn't large enough to fit all of the elements within it.

Comment: Is this this the only element on the page or are there others?

Comment: There are others, as you can see on the gif. If you consider the whole sidebar as just one element then yes, it is the only element in the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried to remove the `absolute` position of the divs encapsulating sound detection details and also refactored some of the code . Below is the code shared.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<body class="bg-black">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sidebar-container" class="py-1.5 bg-gray-300 w-400px h-full absolute z-1 overflow-x-hidden opacity-100 overflow-y-scroll flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <div id="sidebar-logo" class="w-[300px] mx-auto">
                <img class="" src="assets\img\logo-V2\logo-horizontal-black.png">
            </div>

            <hr class="w-[375px] border border-solid border-zinc-700 mx-auto">

            <h3 class="text-center py-3 text-xl text-gray-600 font-semibold">STROBE SYNC MODE</h3>

            <div id="auto-manual-container" class="w-[330px] mx-[35px] flex justify-between">
                <button id="auto" class="w-[150px] h-10 mb-4 bg-white rounded font-bold text-xl text-themeOrange selected" onclick="autoMode()">AUTO</button>
                <button id="manual" class="w-[150px] h-10 mb-4 bg-white rounded font-bold text-xl text-gray-700" onclick="manualMode();">MANUAL</button>
            </div>

            <hr class="w-[375px] border border-solid border-zinc-700 mx-auto">

             <!-- "AM" stands for "Auto Mode" -->
                <div id="input-device-container" class="w-[330px] mx-[35px]">
                    <h5 class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500">INPUT DEVICE</h5>

                    <select id="select-input-device" class="w-full h-10 mb-5 flex mx-auto bg-white rounded outline-none font-semibold text-center text-gray-700" required>
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>SELECT DEVICE</option>
                        <option value="" class="device text-left">&nbsp;Integrated Player</option>
                        <option value="" class="device text-left">&nbsp;Example Device</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div id="frequency-range-focus-container" class="w-[330px] mx-[35px]">
                    <h5 class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500">FREQUENCY RANGE FOCUS</h5>

                    <div id="low-mid-high-container" class="w-full flex justify-between">
                        <button id="low" class="w-[100px] h-6 mb-4 pt-[2px] bg-white rounded font-bold text-base text-themeOrange selected" onclick="low_Btn()">LOW</button>
                        <button id="mid" class="w-[100px] h-6 mb-4 pt-[2px] bg-white rounded font-bold text-base text-gray-700" onclick="mid_Btn()">MID</button>
                        <button id="high" class="w-[100px] h-6 mb-4 pt-[2px] bg-white rounded font-bold text-base text-gray-700" onclick="high_Btn()">HIGH</button>
                    </div>
                    <button id="master" class="w-full h-12 mb-3 pt-[2px] bg-white rounded font-bold text-base text-gray-700" onclick="master_Btn()">MASTER</button>
                </div>

                <div id="detection-sensitivity-container" class="w-[330px] mx-[35px]">
                    <h5 id="sens-label" class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500"></h5>

                    <div id="sens-slider-container" class="w-full">
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="sens-slider w-full" id="sens-slider">
                        <p class="float-left font-regular text-sm text-gray-600">0</p>
                        <p class="float-right font-regular text-sm text-gray-600">100</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div id="strobe-duration-container" class="w-[330px] mx-[35px]">
                    <h5 id="AM-duration-label" class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500"></h5>

                    <div id="duration-slider-container" class="duration-slider-container">
                        <input type="range" min="10" max="1000" value="200" class="duration-slider w-full" id="AM-duration-slider">
                        <p class="float-left font-regular text-sm text-gray-600">10</p>
                        <p class="float-right font-regular text-sm text-gray-600">1000</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div id="sound-detection-details-container" class=" w-[330px] mt-28 mx-[35px]  bottom-[75px]">
                    <h5 class="mt-3 mb-1 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-500">SOUND DETECTION DETAILS</h5>

                    <div id="SDD-container" class="w-full h-40 px-4 bg-white rounded flex flex-col justify-evenly">
                        <div id="SCT-container" class="w-full">
                            <h4 class="float-left font-semibold text-base text-gray-600">SOUND COME THROUGH</h4>
                            <label id="SCT-check-container" class="float-right">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked disabled> <!-- only check when audio coming trough, change with javascript -->
                                <span class="SCT-checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <hr>
                        
                        <div id="tempo-container" class="w-full">
                            <h4 class="float-left font-semibold text-base text-gray-600">TEMPO:</h4>
                            <h4 id="bpm" class="float-right font-semibold text-base text-gray-600">150BPM</h4> <!-- change with javascript -->
                        </div>

                        <hr>
                        
                        <div id="audio-meter-container" class="w-full">
                            <h4 class="float-left font-semibold text-base text-gray-600">AUDIO METER</h4>
                            <label id="AM-check-container" class="float-right"><!-- in this context "AM" stands for "Audio Meter" -->
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="AM-checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div id="AM-on-off-container" class=" w-[330px] mx-[35px] flex justify-between  bottom-0">
                    <button id="AM-off" class="w-[150px] h-10 mb-4 bg-white rounded font-bold text-xl text-themeOrange selected" onclick="AM_turnOff()">OFF</button>
                    <button id="AM-on" class="w-[150px] h-10 mb-4 bg-white rounded font-bold text-xl text-gray-700" onclick="AM_turnOn();">ON</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
</body>
```

> **Note:** Since I don't have the styles defined with id like sidebar, so the sidebar appears in the left side.

ALso you can view [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cKlK2bIW6H?layout=horizontal)